# How to extract double value with the same format from String in java?

Tags: java, string, format, double, extract

i have one string including double value. Now i want to extract same value as double value.
i.e. String val = "0.0001";

Now when i am extracting this value as double, it changes it's format i.e. 1.0E-4
using code: double valAsDouble = new Double(val);

I also want to extract the same value as long and bigdecimal format with the same format.

Please suggest me that how to get it?

Comment: `double`s don't have a format. What you're describing is the result of the round-trip `String->double->String`. It's imprecise.

Comment: 1.0E-4 is the same as 0.0001 but different notation

Comment: What is your problem? whether you use 1.0E-4 * 10000 or you use 0.0001 * 10000 the result is always going to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The double is just a Java representation, the format does not matter at all.

When you are going to print this number and you need a particular layout you can easily change it  using `String.format`.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) you can find the documentation about it.

For example maybe in your case this could be a good solution

```
String myFormattedRepresentation = String.format("%1$,.2f", myDouble);
```